# f.collection_select not showing up

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm working in rails 4 with simple_form and I have two models, one called content and the other one called category. Category has many content and the content belongs to a category. The problem is that when i want a collection_select to show in my form is not showing.
Here is the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @content, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :title, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :tagline, required: true, label: 'Short description', input_html: { maxlength: 20 }%>
  <%= f.input :description, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :price, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :team, required: true, label: 'Team member number' %>
  <%= f.input :equity, required: true, label: 'Equity percentage'%>
  <%= f.input :website, label: 'Website Link', as: :string%>
  <%= f.input :linkedin, label: 'Linkedin Link', as: :string %>
  <%=f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Chose a category"} %>
  <br>
  <%= f.input :copertina, required: true, label: 'Image Cover' %>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Could it be a js problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried   <%= f.association :categories %>?

Comment: aggiungendolo solo cosi non funziona. Come dovrei fare?

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the associated Category for an instance of Content, @content)

collection_select(:content, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, prompt: true)

Answer (score 0):

```
= f.select(:category_id, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id] },{include_blank: true} )
```

Hope, that helps!

Comment: = f.input :category_id, collection: Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id] }, prompt: true Try this once

Comment: Now is showing the title of the collection (category) but not the dropdown

Comment: Which html? This is the new content html: <h4 class="center blue-text text-accent-3">Add a project</h4>

<br>

<%= render 'form' %>

<br>

<%= link_to 'Back', contents_path %>